Does the ill-conditioning of the design matrix affect the ill-conditioning of the Hessian in the context of DL?
I know that when we use the square loss as our cost function in DL, the ill-conditioning of the Hessian is directly tied to that of the design matrix. Does this apply to other cost functions ?
If so, can this be (even loosely) tied to why normalization is effective in dealing with the badly conditioned optimization landscapes of neural nets?.
I am looking for intuitive yet rigorous answers if possible, or references that I could read.
